# Linq To Sql ManyToMany Update Existing Records

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between 2 entities.
UserInfo  and Campaign and the third table  UserInfoCampaigns

On the front end a user should be able to update the user campaigns by using multiple checkboxes.

So I have:

`var  selectedCampaignsIds = new int[] {1,2,3}`

`var user = _extendedUserService.GetUser(new Guid(userId));`

`var newCampaigns =_campaignrepository.GetAllCampaignsByIds(selectedCampaignsIds);`

I can assign newly selected campaigns by following:

```
foreach (var campaign in newCampaigns)
{
    var userInfoCampaign = new UserInfoCampaign { UserInfoId = user.Id, CampaignId = campaign.Id };
    _campaignrepository.SaveUserInfoCampaign(userInfoCampaign);
}
```

My question is how do I update UserInfo campaigns taking into consideration that a user might have or might not have existing campaigns?

Do I delete all existing UserInfoCampaigns and then reassign with new ones? Or there is a more optimal way of updating the UserInfo campaigns without deleting them first using LINQ to SQL?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you'd delete them and recreate them. That's the way I handle this kind of situation of many to many.

Comment: This is the easiest way.  It solves the problem of committing a delete for the removed records.  Otherwise, you persist a campaign that has, say, a couple of userinfos but any old, should-be-removed userinfos will remain indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

If you went for (Delete all) solution then you may consider that the ids will increase in your table in none continues form (I'm assuming that your PK is an int), if you dont care about that then delete them then re-add

if you want the identity  to be in a continues form you may set a flag (IsDeleted) in your campaigns table that refers to the campaign as deleted, you set it to ture when user delete a campaign and set it false when user re-select it from the UI this insure less more records but take a more bit work in your code

Comment: Why would you be concerned about continuous PK?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we just let SQL handle it. You can specify `ON DELETE` on the relationships in SQL, you can `CASCADE` or `SET DEFAULT` or `SET NULL` depending on what behaviour you want.

Here's an example for `ON DELETE CASCADE`: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CascadingDeletes_cs.aspx